# Using AWS Cognito/Amplify just as an OIDC service

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I have an Angular app which I want to secure using AWS Cognito. I initially started using the package `angular-oauth2-oidc` which worked great, I just gave it a few details (issuer, client_id etc) and was up and running.

I'm now looking at implementing Amplify but am finding the examples are doing much more than I want. The examples and quick start all involve creating resources which I don't want, I just want to redirect to the hosted UI and get a token on response.

Can I use Amplify just to handle the logging in (using hosted UI) and the token? I shouldn't need to create any new resources, my applications aren't hosted in AWS, I just want to use the authentication side of things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the amplify [documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start) it states how to use the Amplify JS Framework with existing AWS ressources.

> If you want to use your existing AWS resources with your app you will need to manually configure your app with your current credentials in your code, for example:

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
    identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab', 
    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
    region: 'XX-XXXX-X', 
    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
    userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',
    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID
    userPoolWebClientId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', 
  }
});
```

Comment: So I can ignore all the commands in the quick start like `amplify init`, `amplify auth` etc and just go straight to using it?

Comment: Yes, this is for use in the js frontent. Use it along with the Amplify JS SDK. You can find all the values in the AWS Cognito Console.